# Dollar sign in mdfind shell command

Tags: macos, command-line

I'm a newbie in shell scripting. What's the difference between these two commands? What's the use of the dollar sign?

```
mdfind $'kMDItemFSName="*iValet\'s*"c'
```

```
mdfind 'kMDItemFSName="*iValet\'s*"c'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A dollar sign before a single-quoted string is just another type of string, but it allows C-like escape characters, like `\n` and `\'`.

It was used in the command you mentioned because it contains an escape for the single quote—normal single quoted strings do not allow *any* escapes at all, including escapes of the `'`. Backslashes are interpreted literally. So by using `$'…'` it avoided escaping the double quotes, and allowed the string to have a `'` in it.

There is some more information on this type of string quoting [here on the Bash Hackers Wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting#ansi_c_like_strings).

Comment: I've never heard of C-strings in bash. Neat.